# how to assign a rank for null values with previous first non-null value in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g, ranking

I need to assign a rank to some null values over ordered rows.
My query is like this :

```
with sub as 
(
 select 10 as id, 1 as inx,2 as num from dual
  union all
 select 10 as id, 2 as inx,null as num from dual
  union all
 select 10 as id, 3 as inx,8 as num from dual
  union all
 select 10 as id, 4 as inx,null as num from dual
)
select *
  from sub order by inx
```

and result set is like this :

```
id  inx  num
---------- 
10  1    2
10  2    null
10  3    8
10  4    null
```

i'm tring to set null values with previous first non-null value
for example : num null value should be "2" where inx = 2
and num null value should be "8" where inx = 4 and so on.

thx for any idea..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the values are increasing, you can just use `max()`:

```
select id, inx, max(num) over (partition by id order by inx) as num
```

If they are not increasing and multiple nulls never appear in a sequence, you can use `lag()`:

```
select id, inx,
       (case when num is null
             then lag(num) over (partition by id order by inx)
             else num
        end)as null;
```

If nulls do appear in a sequence, you can use the `ignore nulls` option to `lag()`:

```
select id, inx,
       (case when num is null
             then lag(num ignore nulls) over (partition by id order by inx)
             else num
        end)as null
```